# Differentiability of function $f(x,y) = |x|^a + |x-y|$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to figure out the points at which the function $f(x,y) = |x|^a + |x-y|$ is differentiable. Could you please help me out. I have considered the cases x>0, y>0 etc, but am having difficulty working out what the conditions on x,y have to be such that this function is not differentiable. Many thanks.

Comment: I should point out that $a>0$ here.

Comment: The way I see it, it appears you have no choice but to do it by brute force. That is we have to compute the derivative from the formal definition. I only worked out one partial derivative and it was quite involved already. Many inequalities

Answer (score 1):

At the points with $x\ne 0$, $x\ne y$, a computation shows that partial derivatives are continuous, and therefore the function is differentiable.

When $x=y$, the function fails to have a partial derivative with respect to $y$.

Concerning $x=0$, one distinguishes between $0<a\le 1$ and $a>1$ (see Will Orrick's comment). In the latter case the derivative of $|x|^a$ is $0$ by definition, since the function $|x|^a$ vanishes at superlinear rate. In the former case we do not even have a directional derivative in the direction of vector $(1,1)$ (direction chosen so that the other term is constant).

Answer (score 0):

It is differentiable every where $x \neq y$. In general the point where the absolute value is zero is not differentiable because the limit which defines the derivative does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for this, but could you please expand a bit on how I would rigorously show that this is the case. This question is from a real analysis course, and I'd like to see how this is done from the definition of differentiability of functions from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think you also need to be careful when $a\le1$.  For example, when $a=1,$ you get the term $\lvert x\rvert,$ which is not differentiable at $x=0.$  When $a<1,$ the tangent line of $\lvert x\rvert^a$ approaches the vertical as $x$ approaches $0$ from above or below.